# MYSQL Inner Join if statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

i'm trying to join 3 tables together but use an IF statment to only run a certain query

I have a user table, customer and staff table. The first part below works:

```
SELECT user.`userID`, `username`,  `user`.email, `registeredBy`, `registeredDate`, 
  CONCAT(staff.firstName, ' ' ,staff.lastName) AS staffName FROM `user` 
   INNER JOIN `level` ON `user`.levelID = `level`.levelID 
    INNER JOIN `staff` ON `user`.registeredBy = `staff`.userID
```

I need to view who registered the user which shows fine, but then I need to view either the staff name if the user level is 2 or the customer name if the user level is 1

```
INNER JOIN `staff` ON `user`.userID = staff.userID IF (user.level = 2)
INNER JOIN `customer` ON user.userID = customer.userID IF(user.level = 1)
```

Add the above creates the error

> Not unique table/alias: 'staff'

If I remove the inner join for staff I then get the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   'IF(user.level = 2)' at line 6

I need to only show the customer name or the staff name depending on the level, but I cannot understand how as I am joing the staff table twice. Once to get the memeber of staff who registered the user and then to view the staff name(or customer).

To help make things easier an example of the page I am displaying is:

> username | name | account type |
>   registered by

Hope I haven't made it too confusing to understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Select user.userID
    , username
    , user.email
    , registeredBy, registeredDate
    , Case 
        When User.Level = 2 Then Concat(Level2Staff.firstName, ' ' , Level2Staff.lastName) 
        When User.Level = 1 Then Concat(customer.firstName, ' ' , customer.lastName) 
        End
        AS staffName 
FROM user
    Inner Join level
        On user.levelID = level.levelID 
    Inner Join staff
        On user.registeredBy = staff.UserID
    Left Join customer
        On customer.userID = user.UserID
            And user.level = 1
    Left Join staff As Level2Staff
        On user.userID = Level2Staff.UserID
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one problem the staff seem to always get the same name but the customers work fine?

Comment: So this is a different staff member (i.e., not the registeredby). Np. Will fix

Comment: @Elliott - The trick is to use a different alias for the second join to staff.

Comment: @Elliott - I fixed a typo in the last join and renamed the alias to be more indicative (Level2Staff vs User2Staff). Glad I could help

Comment: Thanks, sorry just one more thing for staff they can either be level 2 for standard or level 4 for admin. I added OR user.level = 4 which works but then I get the staff duplicated again without any names?

Thanks again.

Comment: @Elliott - That logic should go in the case statement: `When User.Level In(2,4) Then ...`

Comment: I have just noticed that for the staff everything including the ID is the same, BUT the staffName?

Comment: @Elliott - From which join? I.e., staff.lastname or Level2Staff.lastname? In this query, staff.lastname is the registeredBy user.

Comment: It seems to show all the staff, but the first staff member is repeated but the staffName is different. But The correct staff memebers are also shown but with no names, as these are shown in the first memeber.

Comment: @Elliott - Did you revise your query given the corrections I made earlier? I.e., the last On clause should be: `On user.userID = Level2Staff.UserID`.

Comment: Sorry just realised I changed something I shouldnt have, works fine :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this works?

```
INNER JOIN `staff` ON `user`.userID = staff.userID AND user.level = 2
INNER JOIN `customer` ON user.userID = customer.userID AND user.level = 1
```