# How do I use an IF statement in an MySQL join query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query that left joins a table in different ways depending on a condition.

```
SELECT m.id, u.first_name AS otherUser
FROM matches AS m
IF (u.id=m.user2ID)
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = m.user1ID
ELSE
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = m.user2ID
ENDIF
WHERE m.user1ID=2 OR m.user2ID=2
```

`matches` is a table with integer columns user1ID and user2ID. `users` is a table containing users of my web application. `users` has a VARCHAR field called `first_name`.

The intention of this query is to get the names of the users matched with the current user.

However, MySQL returns this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'IF (u.id=m.user2ID) LEFT JOIN users 
AS u ON u.id = m.user1ID ELSE LEFT JOIN user' at line 3
```

Why?

Answer (score 16):

Specify the condition as part of the ON clause:

```
SELECT m.id, u.first_name AS otherUser
FROM matches AS m
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (u.id=m.user2ID and u.id = m.user1ID) or (u.id<>m.user2ID and u.id = m.user2ID) 
WHERE m.user1ID=2 OR m.user2ID=2
```

Another way to do the same thing:

```
SELECT m.id, u.first_name AS otherUser
FROM matches AS m
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON IF(u.id=m.user2ID,u.id = m.user1ID,u.id = m.user2ID) 
WHERE m.user1ID=2 OR m.user2ID=2
```

Comment: Thanks, these two queries are generating the right number of results, but strangely returning NULL for all values in the `otherUser` column. It doesn't seem to detect the first names of the users, as shown here http://goo.gl/jg7xp

Comment: it is a LEFT OUTER JOIN so it seems the condition is not satisfied for any row. I have simply copy pasted the conditions from your original query. On a second look, I see something wrong with the conditions - u.id<>m.user2ID and u.id = m.user2ID. Now that would never be true! The other condition is also unlikely although not impossible. Please check your conditions again. Just use this answer as a template and plug in the correct conditions.

Comment: If the query works with the changed conditions pleae edit my answer and change the conditions for benefit of whoever happens to read this later

Answer (score 12):

Use this query:

> <strike>SELECT m.id, u.first_name AS otherUser FROM matches AS m LEFT
> JOIN users AS u ON u.id = m.user1ID AND u.id=m.user2ID LEFT JOIN users
> AS u1 ON u1.id = m.user2ID WHERE m.user1ID=2 OR m.user2ID=2</strike>

## Updated query:

```
SELECT m.id, u.first_name AS otherUser
FROM matches AS m
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = (CASE WHEN u.id=m.user2ID 
                                   THEN m.user1ID
                                   ELSE m.user2ID
                               END)
WHERE m.user1ID=2 OR m.user2ID=2
```

Check this [Source](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/select-with-join-in-an-if-case-statement-possible-520552.html).

Also check this [MYSQL Inner Join if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585338/mysql-inner-join-if-statement) . It might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, this query is generating the right number of results, but strangely returning NULL for all values in the otherUser column. It doesn't seem to detect the first names of the users, as shown here http://goo.gl/jg7xp

Answer (score 2):

You can also have two `LEFT JOIN` on the same table like this...

```
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = m.user1ID
LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON u2.id = m.user2ID
```

This is an alternative to using IF statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `IF THEN ELSE END IF`-stuff in a `SELECT` in this way. However, you can use it in stored procedures and functions.

I would `JOIN` `u.id` with both `m.user1ID` and `m.user2ID` and use `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicates.

There is a `IF()` which you can use in SELECTs, but you can not do flow control with `IF()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
It worked for me. Tried something else like below :

**

```
Create table TEMP1 (ID INT,T_MONTH INT,T_YEAR INT)
INSERT INTO TEMP1 VALUES(1,1,2001)
INSERT INTO TEMP1 VALUES(2,2,2001)
INSERT INTO TEMP1 VALUES(3,3,2001)
```

**

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP2 (T_MONTH INT,T_YEAR INT,FREQUENCY CHAR(1),VAL FLOAT)
INSERT INTO TEMP2 VALUES(1,2001,'M',1.1)
INSERT INTO TEMP2 VALUES(3,2001,'M',1.2)
INSERT INTO TEMP2 VALUES(3,2001,'Q',1.3)
INSERT INTO TEMP2 VALUES(12,2001,'A',1.4)

SELECT * FROM TEMP1 L JOIN TEMP2 H
ON L.T_YEAR = H.T_YEAR
OR (L.T_MONTH = (CASE WHEN H.FREQUENCY='M'
                       THEN H.T_MONTH
                  END)
    OR dbo.GetQuarterFromMonth(L.T_MONTH) = (CASE WHEN H.FREQUENCY = 'Q'
                        THEN dbo.GetQuarterFromMonth(H.T_MONTH)
                        END))
WHERE H.FREQUENCY = 'Q'
```

Here GetQuarterFromMonth is a user defined funtion which returns Quarter for a particular month.

The objective of above query is to inflate the value of Quarter for all the months in table 1. If frequency is annual then in that case the value should be inflated for all the months 1-12 of table 1 which is achieved through first join condition. In case frequency is Monthly then each month from table1 should be mapped to table2. The only unique case is handling quarter frequency.