# In mysql is it possible to write joins depends on if condition

Tags: mysql, join

like :

```
SELECT * FROM (`expenditures`) 
JOIN `categories`
ON `categories`.`cat_id` = `expenditures`.`cat_id` IF(`projects`.`project_id` ! = 0) 
JOIN `projects`  
ON `projects`.`project_id` = `expenditures`.`project_id` 
WHERE `expenditure_id` = $expenditure_id
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an IF statement in an MySQL join query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064183/how-do-i-use-an-if-statement-in-an-mysql-join-query)

Comment: No, it's not possible. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`expenditures`) 
JOIN `categories`
ON `categories`.`cat_id` = `expenditures`.`cat_id`  
JOIN `projects`  
ON `projects`.`project_id` = `expenditures`.`project_id` and `projects`.`project_id` ! = 0
WHERE `expenditure_id` = $expenditure_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (`expenditures`) 
JOIN `categories`
ON `categories`.`cat_id` = `expenditures`.`cat_id`  
JOIN `projects`  
ON `projects`.`project_id` = `expenditures`.`project_id` and `projects`.`project_id` <>  0
WHERE `expenditure_id` = $expenditure_id
```